# JTable does not display values

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am implementing a GUI using java in eclipse IDE. I want to display a table. This is how I implement the program

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.text.TabableView;

import com.model.FloorDetails;

public class ClientGUI {

    private JFrame frame;
    private ClientMain clientMain = new ClientMain();
    private JTable table;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ClientGUI window = new ClientGUI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public ClientGUI() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        table = new JTable();
        table.setBounds(67, 146, 1, 1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(table);
        executeTable();

    }

    public void executeTable() {
        Object[] columns = new String[] {
                "ID", "Room No", "Floor No", "CO2 Level", "Smoke Level", "Status"
        };


        ArrayList<FloorDetails> arrayList = clientMain.getSensors();

        Object[][] data = new Object[arrayList.size()][6];

        for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            data[i][0] = arrayList.get(i).getId();
            data[i][1] = arrayList.get(i).getRoomNo();
            data[i][2] = arrayList.get(i).getFloorNo();
            data[i][3] = arrayList.get(i).getCo2Level();
            data[i][4] = arrayList.get(i).getSmokeLevel();
            data[i][5] = arrayList.get(i).getStatus();
        }

        table = new JTable(data,columns);
        frame.setTitle("Sensor Details");

    }

}
```

`clientMain.getSensors()` method retrieves all the data as expected(I tried printing on the console and everything printed). But when I run the program, it display an empty window.

I tried like this just to see if I am making a mistake when assigning the values to the 2D array but nothing changed

```
        Object[][] data = {
                {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"},
                {"g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"}
        };
```

Where I have done wrong in this program? Thanx in advance!

Comment: Hmmm. `table.setBounds(67, 146, 1, 1);` you are setting the table's height and width to 1? Also, it's not a good idea to use null layouts. Micro-managing all positions and sizes is cumbersome and does not work when switching between environments - e.g. different OS's, with different settings like magnification, font sizes, etc.

Comment: Actually I just dragged and dropped the JTable. I implement only the executeTable() method on my own @TT.

Comment: 1) *"Actually I just dragged and dropped the JTable."* Well, don't. Until you understand how to use the GUI designers **with layouts,** it will produce an ugly & unworkable GUI. More generally: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). ..

Comment: .. 2) Don't add the IDE unless it's relevant to the actual problem. Given the code will likely fail just as badlky in another IDE, it isn't. 3) Add tables at startup, and in a `JScrollPane`. When it's necessary to add / change the data, change the **table model** rather than the component. 4) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one problem in your code is that, you are populating one table and adding another table to the frame. One approach to fix this would be

```
public JTable executeTable(  ) { // Make this method return a JTable
    Object[] columns = new String[] {
            "ID", "Room No", "Floor No", "CO2 Level", "Smoke Level", "Status"
    };

    ArrayList<FloorDetails> arrayList = clientMain.getSensors();

    Object[][] data = new Object[arrayList.size()][6];

    for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
        data[i][0] = arrayList.get(i).getId();
        data[i][1] = arrayList.get(i).getRoomNo();
        data[i][2] = arrayList.get(i).getFloorNo();
        data[i][3] = arrayList.get(i).getCo2Level();
        data[i][4] = arrayList.get(i).getSmokeLevel();
        data[i][5] = arrayList.get(i).getStatus();
    }

    table = new JTable( data, columns);
    return table;
}
```

And then change the initialize method to use this returned table

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    table = executeTable();
    frame.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    frame.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setTitle("Sensor Details");
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

You don't need `window.frame.setVisible(true);` at the `main` method in this approach

Comment: I tried your solution. But still nothing display on GUI. BTW thanx for helping

Comment: @MarketMAD I did an edit on the answer, Let me know if this helped